# Android EditText with a Fixed Suffix

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need an EditText with a fixed Suffix. I'm using a TextWatcher to catch the onTextChanged Event, but if I change the Text again by adding my suffix it causes a stackoverflow exception caused by an infinite recursion.

---

```
 msgtextview.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

               //Doing some other stuff

               msgtextview.setText("Changed Text") //This cause infinite recursion

            }               
        }
```

Here's the code.

Comment: Post your code so someone can help, there are a billion ways to cause an infinite recursion, we need to see what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're having a stack overflow because when you programmatically add the suffix, it triggers an onTextChanged event.

Have you thought about setting a flag right before you set it programmatically so the next time it's called you can know not to add the suffix?

The alternative is to only add the suffix after the user submits your form.

Comment: well, what a shame, i did not think abouk it and was so simple.Tnx (coming from qt4 i was wondering if there was any kind of setSuffix())